# Does umask affect message queues?

Tags: linux, ipc, umask

In Ubuntu Linux, does changing umask of the system (by calling umask() in a program for example), affect the creation and usage of the IPC facilities like message queues on the system?

Answer (score 3):

From [the man page](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/umask.2.html)

> The umask setting also affects the permissions assigned to POSIX IPC objects (mq_open(3), sem_open(3), shm_open(3)), FIFOs (mkfifo(3)), and UNIX domain sockets (unix(7)) created by the process.  The umask does not  affect the permissions assigned to System V IPC objects created by the process using msgget(2), semget(2), shmget(2)).

So if your IPC uses the above, then yes. Can you be more specific?

`strace myprogram | egrep 'mq_open|sem_open|...'` should tell you if you're calling any of these, directly or indirectly.

Comment: I use msgget() to create message queue, so i guess umask has no effect on my ipc. Thx for reply

Comment: Does msgget derive from any of the above? You might want to `strace`